# how to find files written right now in linux?

Tags: linux, file-io

I need to find files written by some script at the current moment in linux. The script is working and writing to some log, txt, some other files, and i would like to find which files exactly are involved. Is it possible?

I tried to do it with find, first by creating the file temp.cnewer with specific timestamp:

```
touch temp.cnewer -t 201012091145
```

and then by finding all files modified after it was created:

```
find / -type f -newer temp.cnewer
```

but it shows too many results. When i checked stat for few of them it shows that modification time is in the future time (don't know how it happen, system time is correct):...

```
Access: 2010-12-09 18:09:14.214730466 +0000
Modify: 2010-12-09 18:09:14.214730466 +0000
Change: 2010-12-09 18:09:14.214730466 +0000
```

Is there other way to select those files?

Comment: So far the solution i use the following: i create 2 files with touch, to create time interval (6 min for example), and in this time interval i start and stop that script: touch now.start -t 201012101022; touch now.end -t 201012101028 .Then between 10-22 and 10-28 i start and stop that script (it creates all logs, open and closes necessary files, etc), and then look for files which were modified with find / -newer now.start -and -not -newer now.end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your modification times are in UTC (time zone +0000), which is why it looks to be in the future.  I believe `touch -t` also uses UTC, which would explain the extra results.  Your original method would probably work OK if you use UTC to set the modification time of your temp.cnewer file.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how long the files are kept open, the `lsof` command might do what you want.  Another option is to run it under `strace` and look for the file open system calls.

Comment: The thing is that script itself writes logs, and processes it starts write their own logs, and i need them all.

Answer (score 1):

It it still has the file open, you could find the script's pid and then

ls -l /proc/PIDNUMBER/fd